# Are there computer searches for new theoretical minerals in a similar vein to Folding@Home or SETI@Home?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, nomenclature, software

As a surprise gift to a friend I would like to discover a new theoretical mineral and have it named after them. I have some understanding that not all minerals have been discovered, and some minerals exist in theory but have not been found on earth.

Is there a computer search that looks for new minerals? Would it be difficult to write one, if one does not exist?

Comment: Done. I've added a bit more information about computing crystalline structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Ross Snider's request, I have moved my comment into an answer - whilst it does not address computational searches for minerals, it touches on the complexities of actually getting a mineral officially named:

The International Mineralogical Association Commission on New Minerals, Nomenclature and Classification seems to [require a physical specimen for consideration for official naming of a new mineral](http://pubsites.uws.edu.au/ima-cnmnc/cnmmn98.pdf). Under current rules, anthropogenic minerals are also excluded, so if you came up with a hypothetical mineral it seems you would have to also find a naturally occurring specimen to get it named.

To add to this, I am not aware of any software for systematically searching for plausible minerals, however computational packages for the simulation of crystalline structures certainly exist. Determining the electronic structure of a crystal - which is what is really required to make conclusions about geometry, stability and so on - generally involves the use of plane wave QM codes such as [VASP](http://www.vasp.at/index.php/about-vasp/59-about-vasp), [CASTEP](http://www.castep.org/) or [ABINIT](http://www.abinit.org/), the latter of which is free. The feasibility of mineralogical calculations using these methods is strongly dependent on how crystalline the mineral is and how ideal it is (from a perspective of not being heavily defected or substituted) as they work within the constraints of a periodic unit cell or supercell.